# Why I can't reach form properties from another file?

Tags: c#, class, public

I'm very new to `C#` and I couldn't figure out reaching variables, form properties and some other methods that reside in one file, from another file. I feel like, this should be as simple as an `#include` directive, but couldn't find a way.

This is the code in file `Form1.cs` created by auto when I create a new Windows Form app in VS. I can reach class definitions that reside in another file named `Class1.cs`; no problem here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace reach_test {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Class1 formName = new Class1(); // this line compiles OK.
            formName.someMethod();          // this line compiles OK.
            this.Text = "Some Header";      // this line compiles OK.
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code in `Class1.cs` file, which I added after. I can not reach, for example, `Form1.Text` property, which reside in file `Form1.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace reach_test {
    public class Class1 {
        public string myText;
        public Class1() {
            myText = "Windows Header";
        }
        public void someMethod() {
            Form1.Text = myText; // this line does not compile!
        }
    }
}
```

Error message is: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Text.get'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# Windows Form application each Forms is a class, if you want to access Form's property
you must create an object like this:

```
 Form1 myForm = new Form1();
myForm.Show()
```

then set public property

```
  myForm.Text = "My text";
```

But i advice change you'r code to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace reach_test {
    public class Class1 {
        public string myText;
        public Class1() {
            myText = "Windows Header";
        }
        public string someMethod() {
           return myText; 
        }
    }
}
```

then set  `Form1.Text`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace reach_test {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Class1 formName = new Class1(); // this line compiles OK.
           this.text= formName.someMethod();          // this line compiles OK.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting name in another class method, returning the name as string and setting the name in it's own class seemed a better choice. Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code `Form1` is a *class name* and so *static properties* only can be accesses in such a manner. `Text` property is not declared as being `static`, that's why you have to create an *instance*:

```
  Form1 myForm = new Form1(); // <- myForm is an instance of Form1 class

  myForm.Text = myText;

  // Probably, you want to do it as well...
  myFrom.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
    Form1.Text = myText; // this line does not compile!
```

You are trying to Call `ClassName.PropertyName` in your Class1 which is wrong, because it should be `InstanceName.PropertyName`. More over you don't have access to Form1's instance from your Class1.

The best thing you can do is

```
public class Class1 {
    public string myText;
    public Class1() {
        myText = "Windows Header";
    }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Class1 formName = new Class1(); 
    this.Text = formName.myText;     
}
```

If you really want to set the `Form1.Text` within `Class1` then you should pass your Form1's instance to `Class1` like below.

```
public class Class1 {
    private string _myText;
    private Form _form1;
    public Class1(Form form1) {
        _myText = "Windows Header";
        _form1 = form1;
    }
    public DoSomething(){
        _form1.Text = _myText;
    }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Class1 formName = new Class1(); 
    formName.DoSomething();     
}
```